# google maps javascript api without browser

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get specific information from google maps which is only available through the JavaScript API. **EDIT**: *In particular I'm interested in the "steps", "legs" and "overview_path" parts of the response. These data can only be received using the JavaScript API; cf. response of the (direct Directions) API call below to see absence of this information; https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=46.210553,6.1430196&destinations=47.54758899999999,7.589662&mode=transit&transit_mode=rail&key=YOUR_API_KEY*

However, I don't need any kind of visualization or maps plot just the json response to my request.

So I'd like to run the request via NodeJS in my terminal with the code below which should output request and response to my terminal.

I’ve come accross the `googlemaps/js-api-loader` library which can be used for testing locally which is what I think I’m doing here (?):

**EDIT**: *I've mistakenly used the DistanceMatrix instead of DirectionsService in my initial question. As pointed out @MrUpsidown in the comments for this I could google-maps-services-js NodeJS library. I updated the code and you could argue that again I can use this library, however, the info I want to have is not included in the response of the API as mentioned above.*

```
const { Loader } = require("@googlemaps/js-api-loader");

const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  version: "weekly"
});

loader.load().then(() => {
  // initialize services
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService()

  directionsService
  .route({
    origin: "Genf",
    destination: "Basel",
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  })
});
```

This is where I'm stuck because running this in the terminal throws an error which I couldn’t fix so far.

```
~$ node index.js
ReferenceError: window is not defined.
```

I’ve read that it might be possible to mock a window or a dom object, but I’m quite new to javascript and webdev so I’d be happy about some help here.

The best solution I've come up with so far is a kind of dirty workaround:  There is a [google sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) which spins up a locally hosted website that can be opened in a browser calling localhost by running

```
~$ npm i
~$ npm start
```

By modifying the request in this sample I’m able to get out the information I need. I automated this using pyppeteer as a headless browser to retrieve the response for further processing.

My hope is that it can be done without pyppeteer / puppeteer as this seems like a bit of overkill (and overengineering) due to my lack of understanding.

Thanks in advance for any tips and hints!

Comment: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js

Comment: [js-api-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader) is a wrapper for loading of Google Maps JavaScript API script in the **browser**, and not necessarily for loading the API using nodejs. The library that MrUpsidown linked above is the library for NodeJS maps usage.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I've mistakenly used the DistanceMatrix instead of DirectionsService but the error and the context stay the same; parts of the data can only be received using the DirectionsService **with the JavaScript API**. I updated the question giving better context and more information.

Comment: Have you checked the link I shared in my first comment? It supports both Directions and DistanceMatrix.

Comment: Yes, and have you read the addenda to my question? The Directions API (also the package that you shared) doesn't give the information I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3):

### Maps Javascript API is a **`CLIENT-SIDE`** Service

The reason why you were having a hard time running the Maps Javascript on the server-side using node is because it was not made to be used that way. Although the [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript) includes [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions), it does not mean that you can use it server-side.

Please do note that it was called `client-side` service because it should be used with a visualization of the data. In this case, loading a map in the browser.

So what should you use then because you want to run the Directions API on the `server-side`?

### Use the Standalone Directions API Web Service

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview) specifically says this:

The Directions API is a web service that uses an HTTP request to return JSON or XML-formatted directions between locations. Directions is available in several forms:

- as a standalone API
- as part of the client-side [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)
- for server-side use as part of the [Client Libraries for Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/client-library)

To do this with node, you can use `axios` by requiring it on your javascript code. There's a [code sample from the Directions API web service documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#ExampleRequests) but I made you a modified one to suit your needs. Especially in fetching `steps`, `legs` and `overview_polyline`.

Here's a code sample using the sample request you provided on your question:

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Geneva&destination=Basel&mode=%20transit&key=API_KEY',
  headers: { }
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  // This is the JSON object result for the directions request
  const result = response.data;
  // Logging the `legs` array
  console.log(result.routes[0].legs);
  // Logging the `steps` array
  console.log(result.routes[0].legs[0].steps);
  // Logging the `overview_polyline`
  console.log(result.routes[0].overview_polyline)
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

You just have to run this code on your terminal after setting up the node environment:

```
node index.js
```

And this will log the results you wanted on the console.

*p.s. you can also use the NodeJs client library the MrUpsidown provided on the comment of your question: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js*

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply!
addressing your questions: 
- i want to do some transformations before plotting, that's why i directly wanna access the data; the end result will be displayed as a map
- the data i'm most (solely) interested in is the **overview_path** (NOT overview_polyline as in your response) which to my knowledge is not available outside the maps JavaScript API

Comment: Apologies for mistooking the `overview_path` with the `overview_polyline`. From what I know from the API documentation, there's a web service called [Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) which has a Snap to Roads functionality wherein you can interpolate a path which will return a smoother path coordinates (Which also includes place_ID as an alternative to coordinates). You can use the` steps array` of result from the Directions API then use it in the Roads API to smoothen it out. I think it's worth checking out and update back here once you're done checking.

Comment: But wouldn't be the steps enough? I'm not sure if the `overview_path` is just the results from the steps contained in a single array. But I'll try to do some testing tomorrow.

Comment: No unfortunately not; the problem with the **Directions API** (and also being different from the *DirectionsService* library within the **JavaScript API**) is that for `travel_mode=rail` the steps don't return a rail route, cf. the API call - link at the beginning of my question. This is probably a bug with the Directions API since `mode=transit` is still in beta. That being said, comparing `steps` and `overview_path` in the response from the JavaScript API, they indeed yield similar information, just the `overview_path` leaving out some coordinates.

Comment: Then the Roads API wouldn't work for your use case right? If so, what I could suggest here is to file a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188841&template=789306) on the Google Issue Tracker for the Directions API web service to also include the `overview_path` similar to the response from Maps Javascript API Directions Service. And see what the Google Engineers think about such feature. Just make sure to put in your use case to increase the possibility of it being worked on and `star` it to keep you up to date.

Comment: Please do note that the Issue Tracker is the authoritative source for public information regarding the feature requests, and all publicly-relevant updates will be posted there. So I could say that this would be the canonical answer that you are looking for. I'll still edit my answer tomorrow to include filing feature request OR if Roads API worked for you. Then up to you if you accept this answer. But all in all, hope I was able to help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me to the feature request page! Well, in all honesty, it still doesn't solve my problem, since i need the data and it might take quite a while until google provides it via the Directions API. Is there really no way to run a client-side library on the server-side? Like mocking windows or something like that? A reply in this way would *really* help me. I can't believe that I'm the first person trying to do something like this. But in any case thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Well my thoughts on why you could be the only one asking this is because, it is called `client-side` for well... for use in `client-side`. And trying to use it for the `server-side` just because a certain feature is missing from the `client-side` version. And this could be even working as intended. As much as I would like to help you with a workaround for this, I'd rather provide an authoritative answer or a documented one. Just like you mentioned on your question, it could cause overengineering. And if filing a feature request would be good.

Comment: You can also try using [Polyline Encoder/Decoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) from the official docs. And see if it works for you. Here's their [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility). This converts the `overview_polyline` into an `overview_path`.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually pretty cool! But it's not very accurate... I tried it on the polyline from the api-call in the question and I don't think it's usable, unfortunately. See screenshot [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6mcg7th8gwdw37f/Screenshot%202023-04-04%20at%2019.05.38.png?dl=0).

Comment: Then a feature request would be good! You should include your feature request on your question for visibility.

Comment: I'm just curious as to what is the use case why you need the `overview_path`? After searching around for a while, I could not find a bug for it and my thoughts on this is that not having the `overview_path` on the web service is _working as intended_.

Comment: sure! i want the list of intermediate coordinate points

Comment: My question is "What is your use case?" because not having the `overview_path` in the webservice seems to be working as intended. because the `overview_path` should not be used in any other place other than the Maps Javascript API. Trying to use the `overview_path` results in other application could be against their ToS. Please see: [***3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services section (d) No Re-Creating Google Products or Features***](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms) if your use case is within the bounds of their ToS.